# rails simple_form fields not directly related to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and using simple form for the first time. I have an article model and tag model. @article.tags give me all the tags related to a the specific article.

I am trying to build a form (like stackoverflow) where the tags can be entered as comma separated values. Since the tags are only names as string values and not objects, how to read these when the form is posted and how to render the html input for this tags textbox using simple form. Also how can I get the tags as comma separated value in edit form.

Comment: Are the tags created before?

Comment: @davidwessman before adding the tags I am planning to check if they already exists in the database, if not create new

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the cocoon gem (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). It is used for nested fields, so you can dynamically add new fields (in this case, new inputs for tags). It is not so complicated to use and it's kinda nice for user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend: [Select2](https://select2.github.io) through the [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) gem.

Especially with what they call [`Tagging`](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags).

I implement it by loading a js:

```
function select2() {
  $('.select2').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    width: '100%'
  });
}

function select2Tags() {
  $('.select2_tags').select2({
    tags: true,
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });
}

$(select2);
$(select2Tags);
```

And in the form I would do:

```
<%= f.association :tags, collection: Tag.all,
                               input_html: {class: 'select2'} %>
```

But this would require the tags to be created before hand.

Comment: Thanks... this works for existing tags.. but what if I want to allow the user to enter the tags which are not already there in the database

Comment: Could be used with just a normal string input and then do some fancy before_save call!